# Stacking columns but not lines in same chart highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have a line chart over a column chart. It works perfectly, the only problem being the lines are not in the right position in the chart(i.e. their positions do not correspond with their value).

I believe this is due to the stacking set to normal. We use an in house application to generate our charts, which means not all properties that are available in Highcharts are exposed, and I do not have a jsfiddle for it.

Therefore my question is this : Is there a way to set stacking for the column chart but disable it on the line chart? I will need to set this in the html file.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/5FkFN/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the API for [`plotOptions.line.stacking`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.stacking) you can explicitly set the stacking value on the line series with this:

```
series: [{
            type: 'line',
            stacking: null,
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up setting stacking explicitly in the html after the charts have been generated, by setting stacking to normal for all the column series and not setting it for the line series.